# Long Running Apps YARN and yarn.nodemanager.log.retain-seconds

Tags: hadoop-yarn

Assume my `yarn.nodemanager.log.retain-seconds` is set to 2 days and my yarn log aggregation is turned off, so every generated log remains in the local filesystem. What would happen if I had a long running job, i.e. Spark Streaming that continued to run over 2 days? Would the logs be deleted from the local filesystem even if the Spark Streaming job continued to run?

There is not much information in the web for the above scenario and in the yarn-site.xml config the `yarn.node.manager.log.retain-seconds` is only described as `Time in seconds to retain user logs. Only applicable if log aggregation is disabled` .